# How can I improve DELETE performance from an SQLite table with foreign keys?

Tags: python, sqlite

Deleting from a table in SQLite with foreign keys enabled seems very slow. Is there anything that can be done to improve the performance (without disabling the foreign keys)?

```py
import time
import sqlite3

def fk_check(state):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE parent (id integer primary key, name)")
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE child (id integer primary key, parent_id references parent)")
    c.execute("CREATE INDEX parentindex ON child(parent_id);")

    c.execute(f"pragma foreign_keys={state};")

    for i in range(10000):
        c.execute("insert into parent (name) values (?);", ('name'+str(i),))

    for i in range(5000, 10000):
        c.execute("insert into child (parent_id) values (?);", (i,))

    start = time.time()
    c.execute("delete from parent where id < 5000")
    took = time.time()-start
    print(f'fk-{state}: {took}')

fk_check('on')
fk_check('off')
fk_check('on')
fk_check('off')
```

Has the following output:

```
fk-on: 0.8750052452087402
fk-off: 0.0007216930389404297
fk-on: 0.8769822120666504
fk-off: 0.0007178783416748047
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes):

> each time an application deletes a row from the parent table, it performs the equivalent of the following SELECT statement to search for referencing rows in the child table:
>
> ```
> SELECT rowid FROM <child-table> WHERE <child-key> = :parent_key_value
> ```
>
> If this SELECT returns any rows at all, then SQLite concludes that deleting the row from the parent table would violate the foreign key constraint and returns an error. Similar queries may be run if the content of the parent key is modified or a new row is inserted into the parent table.

With FKs on, it's doing extra work on each delete. I don't think you can avoid this while still retaining the foreign key constraint.